# Include related data without mapping table

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have 2 models(`Users` and `Teams`) many-to-many related via a third mapping model(`TeamUsers`).
Now I'd like to get the Teams and join the Users, without displaying the mapping tables content in retured JSON.

For example:

```
var teams = await _context
    .Teams
    .Include(t => t.TeamUsers)
    .ThenInclude(u => u.User)
    .ToListAsync();
```

returns:

```
[
    {
        "teamId": 1,
        "name": "Dev Team",
        "avatart": null,
        "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "teamUsers": [
            {
                "teamId": 1,
                "userId": 1,
                "user": {
                    "userId": 1,
                    "firstName": "John",
                    "secondName": null,
                    "lastName": "Doe",
                    "email": null,
                    "avatar": null,
                    "teamUsers": []
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

but I'd like to have this:

```
[
    {
        "teamId": 1,
        "name": "Dev Team",
        "avatart": null,
        "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "teamUsers": [
            {
                "userId": 1,
                "firstName": "christopher",
                "secondName": null,
                "lastName": "elstner",
                "email": null,
                "avatar": null,
                "teamUsers": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Well, if the default entity model doesn't work for you, there is always LINQ `Select`, AutoMapper or similar.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev: can you explain that in more detail, or give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to create a View Model and select the properties.

```
var teams = await _context
.Teams
.Include(t => t.TeamUsers)
.ThenInclude(u => u.User)
.Select(c => new TeamViewModel
        {
            TeamID = c.TeamID,
            Name = c.Name,
            Avatart = c.Avatart,
            CreatedAt = c.createdAt,
            Users = c.TeamUsers.Select(u=>u.User).ToList()
        }).ToListAsync();

        return teams;
```